# Mass of a wire positioned along the interval $[a,\ b]$

Tags: integration

Consider a wire positioned along the interval $[a,\ b]$ on the $x$-axis and having a nonuniform distribution of mass. The mass of the segment lying along the interval $[a,\ x]$ is a function $F(x)$. Find the mass of the rod.

**My answer:**

$m=F(b)$

**My textbook's answer:**

$dm=F(x+dx)-F(x)=dF$

$m=\int_a^b dF(x)=F(b)-F(a)$

Who is right and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not both? Since $F(a)$ is the mass along the segment $[a,a]$, which is just one point, we can asume $F(a)=0$ (and since it is also true that both answers are correct, this has to be the case.)